# SQL calculate date segments within calendar year

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012

What I need is to calculate the missing time periods within the calendar year given a table such as this in SQL:

```
DatesTable
|ID|DateStart   |DateEnd   |
 1  NULL         NULL
 2  2015-1-1     2015-12-31
 3  2015-3-1     2015-12-31
 4  2015-1-1     2015-9-30
 5  2015-1-1     2015-3-31
 5  2015-6-1     2015-12-31
 6  2015-3-1     2015-6-30
 6  2015-7-1     2015-10-31
```

Expected return would be:

```
 1  2015-1-1     2015-12-31
 3  2015-1-1     2015-2-28
 4  2015-10-1    2015-12-31
 5  2015-4-1     2015-5-31
 6  2015-1-1     2015-2-28
 6  2015-11-1    2015-12-31
```

It's essentially work blocks. What I need to show is the part of the calendar year which was NOT worked. So for ID = 3, he worked from 3/1 through the rest of the year. But he did not work from 1/1 till 2/28. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic for results like record ID = 3 ?

Comment: This is a pain in SQL Server 2008.  Can you upgrade to SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Consider it done.  I can run this on 2012 if that helps.

Comment: I'm thinking you are going to have to use a stored proc with a cursor or table variable, although you might be able to do something with a recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `LEAD`, `LAG` window functions available from SQL Server 2012+:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT ID, 
          LAG(DateEnd) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateEnd) AS PrevEnd,
          DateStart,
          DateEnd,
          LEAD(DateStart) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateEnd) AS NextStart
   FROM DatesTable
)
SELECT ID, DateStart, DateEnd
FROM (
-- Get interval right before current [DateStart, DateEnd] interval
SELECT ID, 
       CASE 
          WHEN DateStart IS NULL THEN '20150101'
          WHEN DateStart > start THEN start
          ELSE NULL
       END AS DateStart,
       CASE 
          WHEN DateStart IS NULL THEN '20151231'
          WHEN DateStart > start THEN DATEADD(d, -1, DateStart)
          ELSE NULL
       END AS DateEnd
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COALESCE(DATEADD(d, 1, PrevEnd), '20150101')) x(start)

-- If there is no next interval then get interval right after current 
-- [DateStart, DateEnd] interval (up-to end of year)
UNION ALL

SELECT ID, DATEADD(d, 1, DateEnd) AS DateStart, '20151231' AS DateEnd       
FROM CTE
WHERE DateStart IS NOT NULl    -- Do not re-examine [Null, Null] interval
      AND NextStart IS NULL    -- There is no next [DateStart, DateEnd] interval 
      AND DateEnd < '20151231' -- Current [DateStart, DateEnd] interval  
                               -- does not terminate on 31/12/2015
) AS t
WHERE t.DateStart IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID, DateStart
```

The idea behind the above query is simple: for every `[DateStart, DateEnd]` interval get *'not worked'* interval right before it. If there is no interval following the current interval, then also get successive *'not worked'* interval (if any).

Also note that I assume that if `DateStart` is `NULL` then `DateStart` is also `NULL` for the same `ID`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/15b1a/1)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not too big, this approach will work.  It expands all the days and ids and then re-groups them:

```
with d as (
      select cast('2015-01-01' as date)
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, d)
      from d
      where d < cast('2015-12-31' as date)
     ),
     td as (
      select *
      from d cross join
           (select distinct id from t) t
      where not exists (select 1
                        from t t2
                        where d.d between t2.startdate and t2.enddate
                       )
     )
select id, min(d) as startdate, max(d) as enddate
from (select td.*,
             dateadd(day, - row_number() over (partition by id order by d), d) as grp
      from td
     ) td
group by id, grp
order by id, grp;
```

An alternative method relies on cumulative sums and similar functionality that is much easier to expression in SQL Server 2012+.

Comment: I am running SQL Server 2012.  I have changed the tag associated with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat simpler approach I think.

Basically create a list of dates for all work block ranges (A). Then create a list of dates for the whole year for each ID (B). Then remove the A from B. Compile the remaining list of dates into date ranges for each ID.

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME, @enddate DATETIME
SET @startdate = '2015-01-01'
SET @enddate = '2015-12-31'

--Build date ranges from remaining date list
;WITH dateRange(ID, dates, Grouping)
AS
(
    SELECT dt1.id, dt1.Dates, dt1.Dates + row_number() over (order by dt1.id asc, dt1.Dates desc) AS Grouping
    FROM 
    (
        --Remove (A) from (B)
        SELECT distinct dt.ID, tmp.Dates FROM DatesTable dt
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            --GET (B) here
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, number, @startdate) [Dates]
            FROM master..spt_values
            WHERE type = 'P' AND DATEADD(DAY, number, @startdate) <= @enddate
        ) tmp
        left join
        (
            --GET (A) here
            SELECT DISTINCT T.Id,
               D.Dates
            FROM DatesTable AS T
            INNER JOIN master..spt_values as N on N.number between 0 and datediff(day, T.DateStart, T.DateEnd)
            CROSS APPLY (select dateadd(day, N.number, T.DateStart)) as D(Dates)
            WHERE N.type ='P'
        ) dr
        ON dr.Id = dt.Id and dr.Dates = tmp.Dates
        WHERE dr.id is null
    ) dt1
)
SELECT ID, CAST(MIN(Dates) AS DATE) DateStart, CAST(MAX(Dates) AS DATE) DateEnd
FROM dateRange
GROUP BY ID, Grouping
ORDER BY ID
```

Heres the code:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3615/1

I hope this helps!